# Unable to access keyvault when assigned to group, how to fix that?

Tags: azure, vault, key

I have created a keyvault and added few keys and while creation, provided access to a service principal using azure bicep template.

```
var permissionContributorId = 'f25e0fa2-a7c8-4377-a976-54943a77a395'

resource popKeyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01-preview' = {

  name: keyvaultname

  location: location

  properties: {

    createMode: 'default'

    tenantId: subscription().tenantId

    sku: {

      family: 'A'

      name: 'standard'

    }

    enableRbacAuthorization: true

    enabledForDeployment: true // VMs can retrieve certificates

    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true

    enabledForDiskEncryption: true

  }

}

var roleDefinitionContributor = subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', permissionContributorId)

resource aksIdentityPermission 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = {

  name: guid('${resourceGroup().name}/${popKeyVault.name}/aksApplicationGatewayPermission')

  scope: popKeyVault

  properties: {

    principalId: userId

    roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionContributor

  }

}
```

After creation of keyvault, eventhough I am owner of subscription and even showing in inherited perimissions, I wasn't able to access secrets in the web ui when I tried.

Getting this error.

> The operation is not allowed by RBAC. If role assignments were
> recently changed, please wait several minutes for role assignments to
> become effective.

If I add access to my username manually and provided "Key Vault Administrator" access then it is working.

So, I created a group and added me and my fellow colleagues as members to that group. And when I removed the manual entry above and add this group as key vault administrator. I wasn't able to access again.

The role assignment if you see in the below screenshot.

[role access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IGTj.png)

Suggest me how to fix that?

Also please suggest how to add multiple users,groups,serviceprincipal access in the singel bicep section instead of using multiple entries.